# Group by, annotate and display extra data from parent model in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models related with a foreign key (employee):

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    wage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, default=0)

class Record(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='employee', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateField()
    cash = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, default=0)
```

I would like to obtain a JSON aggregation for an employee describing total cash he earned and the date_ranges:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "position": "",
    "site": "",
    "total_cash": 1500.0,
    "start_date": "",
    "end_date": ""
}
```

I would like to filter the results based on a date range in the future, so annotating the Employee objects is not an option. Or am I wrong here?

What I've done:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'position', 'site', 'wage']


class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee__id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='employee.id')
    employee__name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='employee.name')
    start_date = serializers.DateField()
    end_date = serializers.DateField()
    total_cash = serializers.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ['employee__id', 'employee__name', 'total_cash', 'start_date', 'end_date']
```

In the view I'm overriding the `.get_queryset()` method

```
class RecordView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer
    queryset = Record.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Record.objects.values('employee__id', 'employee__name')\
            .annotate(total_cash=Sum('cash'), start_date=Min('date'), end_date=Max('date'))
```

I'm getting the right query result, but I cannot get the serializer to recognize the `employee__name` or `employee__id` fields. This is the JSON response:

```
{
    "total_cash": 1500.0,
    "start_date": "2020-09-02",
    "end_date": "2020-11-02"
}
```

I also tried to serialize the whole employee object using `employee = EmployeeSerializer()`.

What is the correct way of annotating such queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this way?

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Record.objects.values('employee__id', 'employee__name')\
        .annotate(total_cash=Sum('cash'), start_date=Min('date'), end_date=Max('date'))\
        .values('employee__id','employee__name','total_cash','start_date','end_date')
```

and remove `source` from both fields.

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately the response doesnt't change.

Comment: remove the source from both fields and then try.

Comment: Thanks, removing the source attributes from serializer fields has solved my issue!